# MS ACCESS - VBA - Insert Into SQL adds unwanted data to top of table on form refresh

Tags: vba, ms-access

The below code appends a templated bill of materials to a job card. It adds part and job number to the end of tblMaterialRequiremnt table.. and works!

```
Private Sub Command15_Click()
    
    Dim db        As DAO.Database
    Dim strSQL    As String
    Dim PrtNbrGt  As String
    Dim JbNum     As String
    
    JbNum = Me.[tblManufactured.Job Number]
    PrtNbrGt = Me.SCSPartNumb
    
    Set db = CurrentDb
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblMaterialRequiremnt ( [Customer Part Number], [Job Number] ) " & vbCrLf & _
    "SELECT tbl_BOM_Requirments.RequiredMaterialPrtNum, '" & JbNum & "'" & vbCrLf & _
    "FROM tbl_BOM_Requirments " & vbCrLf & _
    "WHERE (tbl_BOM_Requirments.PrtNmber_LinkField) = """ & PrtNbrGt & """"
    
    db.Execute strSQL
    'Me.Form.Requery
    Me.Form.Refresh
    
    
End Sub
```

The problem is when the form is refreshed the job number is being incorrectly overwritten on the 1st line *(IE at the top)* of the tblMaterialRequiremnt table..
yet there is nothing in the code to suggest updating the 1st record..

Any ideas why a refresh would overwrite the first job number field?

Comment: On a SQL database, there is no "top" or "bottom". You have data that you fetch, and you can specify an order with the "Order by"-clause. If you omit this clause, there is no guaranteed order.

Comment: I very much doubt anything is overwritten. You say the new record shows as first record on form? I would expect it to show as last record. Is there an autonumber ID field in table? Is form based on a query with ORDER BY clause?

Comment: as it happens, you didn't provide enough to information to produce a minimal reproducible example so I can't answer this, but try the troubleshooting technique of printing out stringsql to debug.  stub the part numbers and such and print to debug rather than executing and you should see that the resulting sql doesn't make sense.